# Sending contents of a DOM element to server via post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to send a table to the server and have it come back with a csv file.
I think the only way to do this is to place the table contents into a hidden form element and submit it to the server.

```
<form id='csvForm' method="POST" action="makeCSV.php">
  <input type='hidden' name='content' value='' />
</form>

<input type='button' id='generateCSV' value='CSV' />

<table id='myTable'>
  <tr>
    <td>this is a test</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
$('#generateCSV').on('click', function(){
  // ?????
  $('#csvForm').submit();
});
</script>
```

I am not sure what I need to do at the question mark line to put the html into the hidden form element. I am assuming I need to escape the html dom somehow.

Comment: Personally I think it is better to get just the values you need and send them to server, not whole table. Why you need such think?

Comment: I would avoid sending HTML to the server... this is a code smell... ideally you want something like a JSON representation of the data, you can then build both the HTML table and the CSV from the JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no way around *eventually* parsing out the HTML**, but you do have some ability to decide whether to do this on the server side or the client side.

**If you want to delay parsing until the server side, put `document.getElementById('myTable').outerHTML` into the hidden field**. This will pass a blob of text to the server, and the text will be an HTML representation of the table's DOM. I say "an HTML representation of the table's DOM" because it might not be *exactly* the same as the HTML code on the page, but it should at least be semantically equivalent to that code (plus any changes you might have made in the DOM via JavaScript). On the server side, you'd run this text through some kind of parser, extract the data, and put it into a CSV to return it.

**You could also parse the table on the client-side, perhaps using something akin to the Visitor pattern to walk the table's DOM and build out a different data structure.**. This is nontrivial stuff, but it would save you some bandwidth and server load by transmitting the data in a more compact and easily-parseable form. You could even pass it as CSV, so that the server wouldn't need to convert the data between formats at all; depending on what else you need to do with the data, this might let you cut out the AJAX call entirely.

Comment: Why is there no way of getting around having to parse HTML? Depends on how this problem is tackled... there is no way of getting around this IF the html is what is sent to the server... but to be honest, I would say that it should not be. It would be much more preferable to send over JSON for example... generating the table from that JSON and also the CSV.

Comment: Point taken; I got a little loose with my terminology. A Visitor would be a case of parsing it out of the DOM tree. Or you could render it straight to some text-based format, like my outerHTML-based solution, and then pry the data out of that with a parser or regexes (if you don't mind courting Zalgo) or some other method. The problem with using JSON here is that in order to do that, you first have to get the data out of that tree, and if you can do this, then you may as well just put it straight into CSV (which is the end goal anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this,
You need to first parse table data TABLEDATA

```
var tmp = [];
var TABLEDATA = ''


// Parse table data
$('#tableid').find('tr').each(function() {
    TABLEDATA += "\n";
    tmp = [];
    $($(this)).find('td').each(function() {
        var $th = $(this);
        var text = $th.text();

        tmp.push(text);
   });
   TABLEDATA += tmp.join(",");
});


$('#generateCSV').on('click', function(){
    var form = $('<form></form>');
    $(form).hide().attr('method', 'POST').attr('action', URL);

    var input = $('<input type="hidden" />').attr('name',
                'tabledata').val(TABLEDATA);

    $(form).append(input);

    $(form).appendTo('body').submit();
});
```

Comment: I like this method but you left out the part that I needed the most which was putting the TABLEDATA in there. I just want to send the entire html to the server, I will parse the html into csv on the server side. It wouldnt be as easy as $('#myTable').html() right? Because I think it would need to be escaped somehow.

Comment: @Mike yes you can just post $('#myTable').html() and it should do, but it will be better to use ajax to send the html.

Answer (score 0):

**Client side solution and sending formatted CSV to server side:**

The below will loop through all the table (#myTable) rows and columns and create a CSV output. For the purpose of sending it to the server side I've added it to a hidden field and submit the form (**uncomment the line //$("#csvForm").submit()**).

Here is the sample code:

```
<html>
<body>

    <form id="csvForm" method="POST" action="makeCSV.php">
        <input name="csv_content" type="hidden" value="" />
        <input type="button" id="generateCSV" value="CSV" />
    </form>

    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column1</th>
                <th>Column2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Test1</td>
                <td>Test2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test3</td>
                <td>Test4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- Remove after testing -->
    <p id="generated_csv" style="border:1px solid black;white-space:pre-wrap;"></p>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("#generateCSV").on("click", function(){

        var header_rows = $("#myTable thead tr");   //Get header content
        var body_rows = $("#myTable tbody tr");     //Get body content

        var csv_output = "";

        //Loop through header rows
        //COMMENT FOR LOOP TO REMOVE HEADERS FROM CSV
        for (var r = 0; r < header_rows.length; r++) {
            //Loop through header columns
            for (var c = 0; c < header_rows[0].children.length; c++) {

                //Add header column value
                csv_output += header_rows[r].children[c].textContent+",";

                //Remove comma from last header column value of the row
                if (c == header_rows[0].children.length - 1)
                    csv_output = csv_output.substring(0, csv_output.length - 1);

            };
            //Add return carriage and new line characters at the end of the row
            csv_output += "\r\n";
        };

        //Loop through rows
        for (var r = 0; r < body_rows.length; r++) {
            //Loop through columns
            for (var c = 0; c < body_rows[0].children.length; c++) {

                //Add column value
                csv_output += body_rows[r].children[c].textContent+",";

                //Remove comma from last column value of the row
                if (c == body_rows[0].children.length - 1)
                    csv_output = csv_output.substring(0, csv_output.length - 1);

            };
            //Add return carriage and new line characters at the end of the row
            csv_output += "\r\n";
        };

        //Add CSV output to hidden form control
        $("#csv_output").val(csv_output);

        //Add CSV ouptut to page for testing, REMOVE after testing
        $("#generated_csv").text(csv_output);

        //Submit form to send to server side
        //Uncomment to send to server side
        //$("#csvForm").submit();
    });
    </script>

</body>
```